Till what point will a metal dissolve?
Suppose I throw a huge chunk of a reactive metal such as Calcium into a fixed volume of water. Will the metal keep dissolving into the water until all of it is in aqueous state or will it reach an equilibrium where it won't dissolve anymore?
$$\ce{Ca_{(s)}   -> Ca^{2+} + 2e^- }$$
What I think happens is that the metal keeps dissolving until a strong enough electric field is established which prevents further dissolution. Am I right here?
I am a bit unclear in my electrochemistry knowledge so I need to also ask, is this potential difference equal to the standard electrode potential for this reaction?


Aluminum passivates, so does magnesium,, and alkali metals are too violent. I'd ask this question about calcium.

@OscarLanzi Right, I'd forgotten about that. Fixed it now!

Consider limiting solubility of Ca(OH)2. Because of that, reaction would be slowly converging to equilibrium due kinetic reasons.

@Poutnik which is why I chose that element.

@OscarLanzi I would not like to be the one to formulate the kinetic model. :-)

The question suggests there is electrostatic separation but it ignores the way the reaction actually proceeds. Since the solution formed is electrically neutral it doesn't makes sense to speak of electric fields except perhaps at (1) particle surfaces (where counterions condense) and (2) around ions, but since Ca is neutral the first requires that Ca2+ ions condense on the particle surface. The second case is dealt with by eg ion solution models such as Debye-Huckel.

Depends on the quantity of reactants. 100 g of Ca reacting with 1 ml of H20 in a closed container would indeed react reversibly, i.e., $\ce{Ca + 2H2O <-> Ca (OH)2 + H2}$ with the equilibrium being far to the right. Of course, due to thermal effects, a few molecules of product $\ce{Ca(OH2) + H2}$ might react, forming the reactants.
Drop that lump into a river, though, and it's gone. No calcium can steep in the same river twice., for it is an open system. Ἡράκλειτος ὅτι πάντα χωρεῖ καὶ οὐδὲν μένει, καὶ ποταμοῦ ῥοῇ ἀπεικάζων τὰ ὄντα λέγει ὡς δὶς ἐς τὸν αὐτὸν ποταμὸν οὐκ ἂν ἐμβαίης.

You write the reaction of calcium with water as reversible. It isn't. Rather, assuming that the hydroxide is not passivating, the solution phase equilibrates but the solid matter converts from the original calcium to the precipitated hydroxide. Your calcium would be gone from the beaker, whereas both the metal and the solid hydroxide would be gone if you added enough water from the river to dissolve all of the latter.

@OscarLanzi, it is reversible, as written: "with the equilibrium being far to the right." Not in a beaker, but in a closed system. And only to the extent that a few molecules in the container would rejoin to make the reactants. Yes, it would be like dropping a shuffled pack of cards and expecting them to be sorted, the point I was making. See Infinite Improbability Drive, https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Infinite_Improbability_Drive, for more info. ;-)

Not even sure we can get a few molecules to react. See this question for a clue to what might happen.

Two common metals give an equilibrium state that can be accessed experimentally without blowing you up or burning the lab down.
Magnesium passivates with the formation of the hydroxide, but this becomes sufficiently insoluble for such passivation only after the water has turned alkaline. Hydrogen formed on the surface of the light metal may temporarily flotate it, generating some stirring. If we monitor the pH of the reacting medium we should see it stabilize around 10, corresponding to a saturated binary solution of $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ in water.
Calcium is more vigorously reactive, but still relatively safe. Similarly to magnesium, we should expect eventual equilibration with a satruated binary solution of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ in water, but in this case with a pH between 12 and 13. Take care to exclude carbon dioxide absorption from the air.

Alright but what if the solution already contained Calcium ions to begin with perhaps by dissolving a salt such as Calcium Phosphate initially. Would that change anything?

I ask these questions because I find the concept of Electrode Potential to be a bit confusing at the moment. Any discussion is much appreciated :)
